# Python library requests cannot open a site

Tags: python

```
url = 'http://developer.usa.gov/1usagov.json'
r = requests.get(url)
```

Python code hangs forever and i not behind a http proxy or anything.

Pointing my browser directly to the url works

Comment: Maybe you need some HTTP headers, which the browser provides but your request doesn't.. Also, loading it, it looks like a continuous stream to me rather than a once-off json

Comment: Interesting any ideas how do find that  out what headers i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comment above.. I think your problem is the continuous stream. You need to do something like [in the doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/)

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

if int(r.headers['content-length']) < TOO_LONG:
    # rebuild the content and parse
```

with a `while` instead of `if` if you want a continuous loop.